# Can I install Visual Studio 6 and Visual Studio 2008 on the same machine?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to install visual studio 6 and Visual Studio 2008 both on my machine. Will There be any problems if i do so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes you can. But first install VS 6.0 , Then VS 2008. Else VS 6 will mess around with defaults of VS2008. VS 2008 is Vs 6 aware but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but I'd recommend installing them starting from the earliest version first.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I'm running VS 6.0, VS 2003, 2005 and 2008 on Vista Business. I'd suggest installing them in that order. In addition make sure you install the service packs for each environment after the main install to avoid conflicts, e.g. VS 6.0, VS 6.0 SP1, VS 2003, VS 2003 SP1, VS 2003 SP2, etc.